# Angularjs login form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

hi I was trying to do a log-in form in angular but i don't know where to start, any help or maybe reference would be appreciated 
i tried to type a function that checks username and pass but i can't redirect it to another page
any help please?????????????

here is my html code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="loginform">

    <ion-pane ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Unilever</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      <div class="modal">
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>

  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form ng-submit="doLogin()">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.username" required>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password" required>
        </label>
        <label class="item">
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>

and this is my angular code

    angular.module('loginform.controllers', [])

    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
      // Form data for the login modal
      $scope.loginData = {};

      // Create the`enter code here` login modal that we will use later
      $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
        scope: $scope
      }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
      });

      // Triggered in the login modal to close it
      $scope.closeLogin = function() {
        $scope.modal.hide();
      };

      // Open the login modal
      $scope.login = function() {
        $scope.modal.show();
      };

      // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
      $scope.doLogin = function() {
        if($scope.loginData.username === users.username && $scope.loginData.password===users.password)
          alert("Welcome");



      };
    })

    .controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.users = [
        { username: 'Marwan ', password:'taro', course1:'software engineering', course2:'Web Dev' id: 1 },
        { username: 'Galal', password:'1234', course1:'software engineering' course2:'workflow engines' id: 2 },
      ];
    })

    .controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$location.path('/newpath')` will let you redirect.  Inject the `$location` service in your controller and call the `$location.path` function at the place of your `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this example this will help you:

login.html:

```
 <div class="container" data-ng-controller="login as vm">
<form class="login">
    <p>
        <label for="login">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" data-ng-model="log.email" placeholder="aaa@gmail.com" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" data-ng-model="log.password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </p>
    <p class="login-submit">
        <button type="submit" class="login-button" data-ng-click="vm.login(log)">Login</button>
    </p>
    <p class="forgot-password"><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
</form>
```

login.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'login';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'loginservice', '$location', '$rootScope', login]);

function login(common, loginservice, $location, $rootScope) {
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(controllerId);
    var loggedIn;
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'login';        
    vm.login = function (log) {
        loginservice.getLoginData(log.email, log.password, vm.loginsuccess);
    }
    vm.loginsuccess = function (data) {
        if (data == null) {
            toastr.error('Invalid username and password');
        }
        else {                
            sessionStorage.Id = data;                
            loggedIn = data;
            $location.path('/dashboard');
            $rootScope.$broadcast('logindata', data);
        }

    }        
    activate();

    function activate() {            
        common.activateController([], controllerId)
            .then(function () { log('Activated login View'); });
            $rootScope.$broadcast('logindata', 0);
    }       
}
 })();
```

loginservice.js

```
  (function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'loginservice';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId,
    ['common', loginservice]);

function loginservice(common) {
    var $q = common.$q;

    var service = {
        getLoginData: getLoginData,

    };

    return service;
    function getLoginData(email, password,success) {
        var data;
        if (email === 'parthi' && password === '12345') {
            data= 1;
        }
        else
            data = null;
        return success(data);
    }

}
})();
```